# Override CSS box-shadow with standard border property for IE

Tags: internet-explorer, css

**css for all browsers:**

```
.bordering {
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: #A3815B 0px 1px 3px;
    -moz-box-shadow: #A3815B 0px 1px 3px;
    box-shadow: #A3815B 0px 1px 3px;
}
```

**css for IE:**

```
.bordering {
    border: 1px solid #A3815B;
}
```

when remove `.bordering` class from all-browsers css,that border in `IE` works OK.

How to do,that `box-shadow` works in `FF,Opera` and others and generic `border` works in `IE` at one time.

tried:

```
.bordering {
    -webkit-border-radius: none;
    -moz-border-radius: none;
    border-radius: none;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    -moz-box-shadow: none;
    box-shadow: none;
}
```

didn't help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make a separate CSS for IE like `ie.css` and link it to your HTML page with this:

```
<![if IE]>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/ie.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<![endif]>
```

Your CSS will be only included if IE is detected.

After that, put your `.bordering` CSS in your `style.css` (for all browser) and put `border: xxx` only in `ie.css`.

It should work. I made it a lot of times.

Comment: i have separate file for IE,that I mentioned in my post

Answer (score 2):

Put an `ie` class using conditional comments in your HTML tag-like this

```
<!--[if IE]><html class="ie"><![endif]-->
<!--[if !IE]><!--><html><!--<![endif]-->
```

(you might want to read http://paulirish.com/2008/conditional-stylesheets-vs-css-hacks-answer-neither/ )

Then set the styles for IE like this:

```
.ie .bordering {
    /* your styles for IE */
}
```

However, I do not understand why you would wish to suppress the box-shadow and border-radius for IE. IE9 supports them and they simply degrade to no shadow and rectangles for IE8 and older.

---

Note

Be [careful with using `box-shadow` on elements with large dimensions](http://html5please.com/#box-shadow). Same goes for `border-radius`.

Comment: i have separate file for IE,that I mentioned in my post